# iOS - filtered view of address book

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

In my app I want to open the address book view controller to add contacts. Now I get a view that shows all the contacts in the iPhone. But I want to get only **some** of the contacts (based on whether they are registered to the app).
My code that is showing the address book is:

```
_addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is it possible to filter the contacts in a way that it'll show only some of them?
(maybe by an array of phone numbers or any other predicate). I mean, that I want to use all the functionality of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, but that it'll show only some of the contacts.

Or do I have to get an array of the phones I want to present and then create a UITableViewController that presents my created array?

Comment: You can create a function in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController which deals with retrieving and filtering contacts (or a constructor). Call it before presenting the view controller.

Comment: can you give an example for how to filter it?